# Okular - open links in a new tab or new windows

Tags: pdf, okular

I want Okular opens pdf links in a new tab or better in a new window.
I have enabled open new files in a new tab, but it doesn't work : Okular opens the new file instead of the previous file : one window, one tab with the link opened, the original document is vanished.

Here an example :

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c8l2kzr9l5dnptc/AADt4qbLaIDiKnthmo8CeeqHa?dl=0

Essai.pdf has a link on bob.pdf (click on the picture)
(Evince or Adobe Reader XI open the link in a new windows.)

Any idea to make it work ?

Ubuntu 16.04 Okular Version 0.24.2
Using KDE Development Platform 4.14.16

Comment: "but it doesn't work" ... so what happens?

Comment: It opens instead of the previous  file : one window, one tab with the link opened, the original document is vanished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Okular version 1.3.3, where it can be easily done.  Here are the steps:

1. Open okular with any pdf file.
2. On the top, the options menu appears.  Click on "Settings".
3. Choose "Configure Okular" from the list of actions.
4. In the subtopics that open up, choose "General".  Usually, it will be chosen by default.  If not, choose it.
5. The first section is called "Appearance".  Skip it.  The second one is called "Program features". In it, there is one line that says "Open new files in tabs".  Click on the square next to it to activate it.

Now if you open any new file, whether from the pulldown menu or from a console, it will open in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like for the new Okular, even after the setup in the new files open tab is there

- if you open the file via the context menu via Okular it opens as a window,
- but if you drag and drop, or open the file via Okular open, it opens in the new tab.